# getting a name error in my code after i tried printing a variable created in an if statement in python

Tags: python

Python program to calculate  the cost of sending a parcel.

The below program is giving a name error when trying to print the total cost:

```
price_of_parcel = float(input(" enter the price of parcel in rands (R) : R "))
total_distance = float(input(" enter the total distance to the parcel destination in (km): km "))
parcel_route = input(" do you want it by Air or Freight? (Air / Freight): ").strip().lower()
parcel_insurance = input(" do u want full insurance or limited insurance? ( Full / Limited) : ").strip().lower()
parcel_nature = input(" do you want parcel as gift or as no gift? (Gift / No Gift) : ").strip().lower()
parcel_urgency = input( " do you want a standard or priority delivery? ( Priority / Standadard ) : ").strip().lower()

if parcel_route == "Air" :
    p_route = total_distance * 0.36
    totalcost = p_route 


if parcel_route == " freight " :
    p_route =  total_distance * 0.25
    totalcost = p_route

if parcel_insurance == " full " :
    p_insurance = 50.00
    totalcost = p_route + p_insurance

if parcel_insurance == " limited " : 
    p_insurance = 25.00
    totalcost = p_route + p_insurance


if parcel_nature == " gift" :
    p_gift = 15.00
    totalcost = p_route + p_insurance + p_gift

if parcel_nature == " no gift " :
    p_gift = 0
    totalcost = p_route + p_insurance + p_gift

if parcel_urgency == " Priority" :
    urgency = 50.00
    totalcost = p_route + p_insurance + p_gift + urgency

if parcel_urgency == " standard " :
    urgency = 20.00
    totalcost = p_route + p_insurance + p_gift + urgency


if  parcel_route == "air" and (parcel_insurance == " full" or "limited") and (parcel_nature == "gift" or "no gift") and (parcel_urgency == "priority" or "standard"):
    totalcost = totalcost = p_route + p_insurance + p_gift + urgency
    print( " the total cost for the parcel is : " + str(totalcost))

else:
    if parcel_route == "freight" and (parcel_insurance == " full" or "limited") and (parcel_nature == "gift" or "no gift") and (parcel_urgency == "priority" or "standard"):
        totalcost = p_route + p_insurance + p_gift + urgency
        print( " the total cost for the parcel is : " + str( totalcost))
```

The name error states that the variable created within the if statement is not defined.

I have tried a few things but the code does not seem to work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the full error message

Answer (score 1):

I would predefine all the variables at the top i.e.

```py
p_route = 0
p_insurance = 0 
p_gift = 0
urgency = 0
```

You probably don't hit some of the if's with your input, creating one, or more of these variables.

Ah, and also - put the above more into "if - elif - else", you don't need to check some of the conditions, once some earlier ones are satisfied...

For your ref: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm

Answer (score 1):

You bug is here -

```
parcel_route = input(" do you want it by Air or Freight? (Air / Freight): ").strip().lower()
```

`parcel_route` is a string in lower case and with no trailing or leading spaces. Because you have used `strip() and lower()`

But, in your `if` clause you have capital letter and spaces too!

```
if parcel_route == "Air" :
    p_route = total_distance * 0.36
    totalcost = p_route 


if parcel_route == " freight " :
    p_route =  total_distance * 0.25
    totalcost = p_route
```

As a result, neither of the two `if` block is executed and your `p_route` variable is never set!

Comment: i did correct it however the result of the compiled code is wrong, don't know why but thanks anyways